# Doing "!" by everything I add the app

Tags: android, android-layout

This is the first time I work with apps, so if you know a site where I can go ahead with that from then it will be super or like I have the brand new version of eclipse

This is the first time I have to work with apps for android. is in my path: **ABSB/res/layout/activity_main.xml**

into the file I am working to add and delete things but no matter what I do then there's always! by pictures or my button.

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Show img here to what i mean on my problem! [CLICK HER](http://billedeupload.dk/images/idc8s.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about it. It's just a lint warning. It doesn't need to be followed.

If you hover your mouse over it. It will tell you that your image needs a string resource, so that it can be localized more easily. If it's not that specific message exactly, it will be a similar innocuous warning.

Comment: So I do not think it's there at all?

Comment: Yeah, don't pay any attention to it.

Answer (score 0):

That's just Eclipse warning you of potential issues with your code. If you hover over the icon in the file itself (next to the line number) it will show the warning message. In this case it will be something along the lines of:

> [Accessibility] Missing contentDescription attribute on image

You can probably safely ignore it in this case.

Comment: Okay thanks for help. I thought first it was something that will affect my app

Answer (score 0):

Hover your mouse over the yellow underlined word (like ImageView in the picture). It will tell you whats wrong. But it is just a warning not an error.

Comment: When I hover the mouse over the image so there will be a box pops up and says "imageView1: [accessibility] Missing contentDescription attribute on image"